# How to set specific instance attribute in Geometry node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I create a point attribute “Size” by store named attribute, for exampe i have 10 points, how to set the fifth point’ “Size” by node?

does blender has geomety nodes system  support script like houdini attribute wrangle?

or actually I need a node like Set Point Radius for custom attribute “Size” which i cannot find that…

Answer (score 5):

Store $24601$ for the fifth (0-based indexing, so index $4$) point, and $0$ otherwise:

[image]

Change the value for the fifth point, but keep the old value for other points:

[image]

Comment: thx~ it's exactly what i want